# BlackBerry Code Signing on Linux without GUI

Tags: linux, blackberry, automation, code-signing, command-line-interface

After a lot of searching I have yet to find a way to sign a BlackBerry application on a Linux distribution with no GUI.

As of right now I'm getting the error "Unable to request signatures until this application has completed the initial key generation.". The problem is I'm not able to register the CSI files it seems via CLI. Has anyone accomplished this without setting up X11?

Comment: The ci tag was meant for continuous integration but CLI is probably a better tag to use anyways.

Comment: Can you use a remote X11 server, on you desktop?  Just for key import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, its definitely possible to do this on a headless Linux box.  Heck, I do it on a headless Solaris/UltraSPARC server :-)

For actually running the tool, I like http://bb-ant-tools.sf.net/ .  If you are using an older version of the signature tool, you may need to make some modifications as described on http://slashdev.ca/ .

While the tool is fully controllable from command-line parameters, it does unfortunately still require access to a running X server to function.  The workaround for this is to install "Xvfb" (a fake X server for purposes like this), launch it in the background on your system, then set the DISPLAY variable so the signature tool will use it for its non-interactive GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry sigtool may not be supported in Linux and it may be only partially working.  BB dev tools are still Windows-centric.